# import csv file and send keys to website (Python Selenium)

Tags: selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

I try to send key from my CSV file into the site's form. Here is the code which I wrote so far but how can I connect it with my csv file? I started with selenium so sry if something is not clear enough. Have a nice day and stay safe :)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time 
import csv


PATH = r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"



driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://shop.jaegermeister.de/account/index/sTarget/shotmachine")
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("field-wrap__checker").click()
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("firstname")
elem.send_keys("Max")
time.sleep(1)


elem = driver.find_element_by_id("lastname")
elem.send_keys("Musterman")
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='register_personal_birthdate']/option[4]").click()
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='jae-registration-form']/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/select/option[2]").click()
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='jae-registration-form']/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/select/option[6]").click()
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='register_personal_email']")
elem.send_keys("max@gmail.com")
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='register_personal_password']")
elem.send_keys("Password123")
time.sleep(1)


elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='city']")
elem.send_keys("Cityxyz")


elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='country']/option[2]").click()


elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='jae-registration-form']/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/label/span[1]").click()
```

Comment: Are the values (i.e last name, email id, pswrd etc) stored in the csv file?

Comment: they are from the website  but yes I have a csv with columns

Comment: Ok...So u wanna extract those values from the csv and send those values to the website. Am I right?

Comment: exactly! thats what I try to achieve

Comment: Check whether my answer satisfies ur requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the csv is like:

[image]

To extract data from this csv file, u can simply use `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Test.csv')

details_lst = []

for column in df.columns:
    details_lst.append(df[column][0])
```

Output:

```
['Max', 'Musterman', 'max@gmail.com', 'Password123']
```

U can then iterate over this list and send the values to the website. Hope that this helps!

Comment: Okay...BTW, is this how even ur csv looks like?

Comment: hey unfortunately my csv isnt filled in the website from but I have no errors too. Here is my code https://prnt.sc/uw82zh and here is mycsv https://prnt.sc/uw83zh

Comment: U are not sending the keys to the browser. Just add ```elem.send_keys``` to ur code.

Comment: U can't send a print statement. Try this:
```elem.send_keys(df['vorname'][0])```. Do the same for the username. It should work. If u still get any errors, pls let me know. I am there to help u!

Comment: thank you sooooo much your the best works now. Do you know how I manage that the form is filled with the csv details from first row and after that again with the second row and so on until every row was entered?

Comment: And could u rephrase ur question? I am not able to understand it properly. Do u wanna loop through all rows and enter the details in the website? Is tht wht u wanna do?

Comment: yes thats what I wanna do. yes I will accept ur anwser

Comment: Okay...But then, u only have one login form to fill right? How can u enter all the data in that form? Do u wanna open multiple forms and enter the data?

Comment: I want to enter one form with multiple data from csv

Comment: How would that work? Bcs there are only 4 fields to fill out in the form. A screenshot of the form would help.

Comment: I did the code already for this form https://prnt.sc/ux726m now I need to send the form and then go to the next row and send it.... and so on

Comment: Okay...U already know the sending part of it. Maybe I can just help u with extracting data from the csv.

Comment: Replace the ```for loop``` in the code with this ```for loop```: ```for x in range(len(df)):
    for column in df.columns:
        details_lst.append(df[column][x])```

Comment: The formatting is not proper, but I hope that u can make it out. In the previous code, u had it as ```df['column'][0]```, which only returns the values in the first row. Now, the same thing is repeated, but the index 0 at the end keeps increasing every time. This extracts all the values in all the rows. I added 2 more rows to the csv, and here is the output: ```['Max', 'Musterman', 'max@gmail.com', 'Password123', 'Test', 'New', 'test@gmail.com', 'testpswrd', 'Test2', 'New2', 'test2@gmail.com', 'test2pswrd']```